# How to Initialize custom class/object within controller using Objective-C on the Iphone

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've got a simple "model" class like so (complete with constructor of course)

```
@implementation Widget
@synthesize name;
@synthesize color;

- (id) init 
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.name = @"Default Name";
        self.color = @"brown";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I've declared it as an internal member to my controller like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Widget.h"

@interface testerViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField    *stuffField;
    Widget *widget;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *stuffField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Widget *widget;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

and... I'm trying to initialize it within my controller like so:

```
#import "testerViewController.h"
@implementation testerViewController
@synthesize stuffField;
@synthesize widget;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    stuffField.text = widget.name;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        widget = [[Widget alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

but.. it doesn't seem to be initializing my object because my textfield comes up blank every time.  Any clues?

Comment: Add a break point on buttonPressed: and make sure it is actually being called. While you are there you can also hover over widget.name and inspect its value.

Comment: I'm a little too used to the visual studio debugger :( ... is it me or are the values in hex when I traverse the properties in the debugger??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

-(void) viewDidLoad{} method to initiliaze your data

in your interface class use @class Widget instead of #import "Widget.h"

and in your implementation class use #import "Widget.h"

and make sure you come into your buttonPressed handler!